# qt5- unexpected reloc type 0x03 on imx6 arm board

Tags: arm, qt5, cross-compiling, debian-based

Cross compiled Qt-5.x.x with xcb. Using arm toolchain. Arm board has debian 6. Installed glib and required libraries for qt. While running cross compiled qt it gave an error saying:

```
./analogclock: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/local/qt-fpic/qt-5.1.1/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: unexpected reloc type 0x03
```

ldd ./analogclock

```
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/local/qt-fpic/qt-5.1.1/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x402db000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/local/qt-fpic/qt-5.1.1/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x40621000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x4008c000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x40184000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x40b0e000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x40109000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x40114000)
    libgstbase-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so.0 (0x40225000)
    libgstcontroller-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstcontroller-0.10.so.0 (0x4026d000)
    libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 (0x40be3000)
    libGLESv2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libGLESv2.so.2 (0x402a1000)
    libEGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libEGL.so.1 (0x40057000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x4002e000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x40cb0000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x40d94000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x4015c000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x402bc000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x4006e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x40098000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libpcre.so.3 (0x40e3c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x40e7f000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x40fb0000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x400e5000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x40fc4000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdrm.so.2 (0x40170000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0x400bf000)
```

Can anybody suggest me what has gone wrong?